# Simulate User-Agent click in browser with JS

Tags: javascript, web, webgl

I would like to simulate a real user agent click in chrome to test a bot on my WebGL application. Is there a way to do it in JavaScript or should I use Selenium from an external application (I do not want to lose the focus on other windows during the bot is running)?

Comment: DOMNODE.click() tried this?

Comment: Yes I tried but it create a not trusted event (security logic) I would like to know if it's possible to bypass the not trusted event.

Comment: OK so you marked as duplicate my question also it's absolutely not the same question...